# Notification timer using users timezone

Tags: c#

I am creating a notifcation timer which is triggering an event once its (in that example) 18 UTC. Since that timer is going to be used by someone using UTC and some CET / CEST I am trying to match the timezone

Thats the code for UTC

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.test == true && tS == ((18 * 60) - Convert.ToInt32(Properties.Settings.Default.notifierTime)) * 60)
```

Event is triggering at 18 UTC minus the time being set by the user.

I was thinking of something 
like

```cs
if (Properties.Settings.Default.test == true && tS == (((18 + timezone) * 60) - Convert.ToInt32(Properties.Settings.Default.notifierTime)) * 60)
```

So I´d let the user manually select the timezone hes in and then add / subtract that.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Don't use a timezone.  The timer's Interval should be notifierTime - DateTime.UtcNow.  Add 24 hours if it is negative.

Answer (score 0):

You have System.TimezoneInfo class that provides api for conversion between zones including daylight saving, etc...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo